# Sub array that produces a given sum and product

Tags: algorithm

Given an array of length N. How will you find the minimum length 
contiguous sub-array of whose sum is S and whose product is P.
For eg `5 6 1 4 6 2 9 7` `for S = 17, Ans = [6, 2, 9]` `for P = 24, Ans = [4 6]`.

Comment: I'd just sort the numbers from highest to lowest and brute force it.

Comment: If you sort the numbers, you'll lose the original ordering and as we need a contiguous sub-array, this is not possible.

Comment: whose sum is S *OR* whose product is P?

Comment: As a first attempt, brute force should be adequate without any sorting. In practice, it's going to O(N) is it not? AND/ OR don't appear to make it more interesting.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand the question originally. You could traverse the array in a non-linear order, checking the highest numbers first, and then the lower (or vice-versa; set up some criterion for each case).

Comment: That would require sorting/indexing, which is expensive relative to the rest of the task.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just go from left to right, and sum all the numbers, if the sum > S, then throw away left ones.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class test {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        int[] array = {5, 6, 1, 4, 6, 2, 9, 7};
        int length = array.length;
        int S = 17;
        int sum = 0;                       // current sum of sub array, assume all positive
        int start = 0;                     // current start of sub array
        int minLength = array.length + 1;  // length of minimum sub array found
        int minStart = 0;                  // start of of minimum sub array found
        for (int index = 0; index < length; index++) {
          sum = sum + array[index];
          // Find by add to right
          if (sum == S && index - start + 1 < minLength) {
              minLength = index - start + 1;
              minStart = start;
          }
          while (sum >= S) {
            sum = sum - array[start];
            start++;
            // Find by minus from left
            if (sum == S && index - start + 1 < minLength) {
                minLength = index - start + 1;
                minStart = start;
            }
          }
        }
        // Found
        if (minLength != length + 1) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Arrays.copyOfRange(array, minStart, minStart + minLength)));
        }
    }
}
```

---

For your example, I think it is *OR*.

*Product* is nothing different from *sum*, except for calculation.

Comment: @usercccd, apologize for my carelessness. Here is the fixed full version.

Comment: Hey, your code does not work for {2, 6, 6, -2}. I think it only works for positive nos, Is this correct. I need an universal solution.

Comment: I have stated in the comment that _current sum of sub array, assume all positive_. If this assumption is not valid, just fix that single line yourself. I suspect this is actually **homework**, otherwise, this assumption is pretty much fine.

Answer (score 1):

pseudocode:

```
subStart = 0;
Sum = 0
for (i = 0; i< array.Length; i++)
    Sum = Sum + array[i];
    if (Sum < targetSum) continue;
    if (Sum == targetSum) result = min(result, i - subStart +1);
    while (Sum >= targetSum)
        Sum = Sum - array[subStart];
        subStart++;
```

I think that'll find the result with one pass through the array.   There's a bit of detail missing there in the `result` value.  Needs a bit more complexity there to be able to return the actual subarray if needed.

To find the Product sub-array just substitute multiplication/division for addition/subtraction in the above algorithm

Comment: @Jean-François Corbett: Why not?  As the sub-array you've got the total of slides through the main array you should find all possible sub-arrays with the target total.  you just keep the shotest one as the result.  That's what i meant by `result - min(result, i - subStart +1)`

Answer (score 1):

Put two indices on the array. Lets call them i and j. Initially j = 1 and i =0. If the product between i and j is less than P, increment j. If it is greater than P, increment i. If we get something equal to p, sum up the elements (instead of summing up everytime, maintain an array where S(i) is the sum of everything to the left of it. Compute sum from i to j as S(i) - S(j)) and see whether you get S. Stop when j falls out of the array length.

This is O(n).

Comment: This was for the subarray sum to be S AND product to be P.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hashmap to find the answer for product in O(N) time with extra space.