# Sub Array whose product equals N

Tags: algorithm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sub array that produces a given sum and product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5535040/sub-array-that-produces-a-given-sum-and-product)

Given an array, find a sub array where product of the elements equals N.
This is my attempt

```
P = 1
Make an another array arr1
for  i = 0 to n-1
  arr1[i] = P
  P *= arr1[i]
put elements, index of arr1 in hash table
for i = 0 to n-1
  search in hash table for P/arr1[i]
  if found
    return [i+1 ... index in hash table]
```

Is this correct. Any other simpler solution.

Comment: By "sub array" you mean a contiguous block of elements?

Comment: Is N an arbitrary number, or the size of the original array?

Comment: Your posted code can't be correct - you only reference the new array `arr1`.  So P will always be 1.   If you change the line to `P*=arr0[i]`, you still have a problem - it will only find subarrays that ended at the last index.  You would need an inner loop from i+1..n to find other subarrays.

Answer (score 4):

It can be solved in O(n) time and O(1) memory, with just 2 additional pointers and current product. The idea is to use sliding window. Keep two pointers, p1 and p2. Initially they both point to the first element of the array, product equals to 1. While the product is less then n move p2 right and multiply product by element at p2. When you reach n or more: if product == n return p1 and p2, else move p1 right and repeat it until p2 reaches the end of the array.

Comment: +1 I was going to suggest the same.

Comment: This is not O(n) time, it's O(n**2) time. Consider the case where the product of all the numbers in the array is less than th enumber you are searching for.

Comment: We move n - 1 time p2 right and then move n - 1 times p1 right. The idea is that at all we do not more tahn 2*n moves.

Comment: +1 implemented the sliding window in Python. Note that p2 termination condition should be `<=`, not `<`.

Comment: Good solution. Be aware that this makes the assumption that multiplication/division of numbers ~N is a constant time operation.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is basically sound. It is simple and has `O(n)` time complexity (provided the hash table insertion and lookup are both `O(1)`). Since in the worst case any solution needs to examine each element at least once, `O(n)` is as good as you can get.

There are two questions about the division:

1. I assume `P/arr1[i]` means `N/arr1[i]`.
2. It is not obvious whether it's an integer division (in which case your solution is incorrect) or a floating-point one (in which case the code is exposed to floating-point issues). To bullet-proof this, you need to have an `if` statement around the search to make sure `N` is divisible by `arr1[i]`.

Also, I think your indexing may be messed up, but I don't have time right now to check it in detail.

Answer (score 1):

The sliding window algorithm suggested by [Artem Volkhin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5581529/sub-array-whose-product-equals-n/5582030#5582030) is of `O(n)` complexity.

#### Advantages

- Very fast - `O(n)`, single pass.
- Iteration is always forward directed - can be used with linked lists.
- In-place, memory-efficient.
- No calculation overhead - best case is O(1).

#### Disadvantages

- All numbers should be > 1, as it relies on the fact that the multiplication increases as we move the second pointer forward.

#### Python implementation

```
def sliding_window(seq, n):   
    low,high=0,0              # Low index, High index
    cur_sum=seq[low]          
    while high<=len(seq):
        if cur_sum==n:        # Match found, return indices
            return low, high  
        elif cur_sum<n:       # Sum to low, increase high index
            high+=1
            cur_sum*=seq[high]
        else:
            cur_sum/=seq[low] # Sum to high, increase low index
            low+=1
     return None, None        # No match, Return
```

#### Example

```
>>> ls=range(1,11)
>>> print ls
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> 
>>> N=336     # 6*7*8
>>> print sliding_window(ls, N)
(5, 7)        # Indices
```

Answer (score 0):

how about (in c++):

```
// returns true if found and sub-array indices in low & high, false otherwise

bool findprod(int arr[], int size, int N, int& low, int& high)
{
  int prod = 1;
  for (low = high = 0; high < size; ++high) {
    prod *= arr[high];
    if (prod < N) continue;
    if (prod > N) 
      for (; prod > N && low <= high; ++low)
        prod /= arr[low];
    if (prod == N) break; // found
  }
  return high < size;
}
```

(same solution as with @Artem, as I see)